# Magento 1: unable to sort grid by custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, grid

I have **added the special_price attribute to the catalog product grid** using *event observer* with the following code.

**Filtering works fine however sorting does not work**, if anyone could help that'd be great.

NB: I'm using the `core_layout_block_create_after` event instead of the `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` event as often suggested on SE because I've got a massaction item that exports the grid to CSV. The fields added via my observer are not added to the CSV if I use `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.1.11</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- To register the controller action -->
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
                <observers>
                    <module_custom_register>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>registerController</method>
                    </module_custom_register>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
            <!-- Called after creating a block -->
            <core_layout_block_create_after>
                <observers>
                    <module_custom_before_block>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>blockCreateAfter</method>
                    </module_custom_before_block>
                </observers>
            </core_layout_block_create_after>
            <!-- Called before loading an EAV collection -->
            <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <module_custom_before_eav_load_collection>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeEavCollectionLoad</method>
                    </module_custom_before_eav_load_collection>
                </observers>
            </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Observer.php:

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function registerController(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'adminhtml_catalog_product_grid':
            case 'adminhtml_catalog_product_index':
                Mage::register('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid', true);
                break;

        }

        return $this;
    }

/**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function blockCreateAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        if($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid)
        {
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore((int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0));

            $block->addColumnAfter(
                'special_price',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sale Price'),
                    'type'  => 'price',
                    'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                    'index' => 'special_price'
                ),
                'price'
            );
        }
    }

    public function beforeEavCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::registry('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid'))
        {
            $collection = $observer->getCollection();
            if (!isset($collection)) {
                return;
            }

            if ($collection instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection) {

                $store = Mage::app()->getStore((int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0));

                if ($store->getId())
                {
                    // Add the special price
                    $collection->joinAttribute('special_price', 'catalog_product/special_price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
                }
                else {
                    // Add the special price
                    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , can we do this using overwrite product grid block instead using event ?

Comment: Yes but using observers is recommended because overwriting blocks can cause conflicts between modules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question.

After a lot of debugging, I've found those interesting lines under the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` model:

```
    public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = 'desc')
    {
        if ($attribute == 'price') {
            $this->addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        } else {
            parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

It seems like Magento team hardcoded the way the price ordering is rendered, that's why I was getting such a different result when trying to sort by special price.

Well the only way to fix this was to override that module and change the function to this:

```
public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = 'desc')
{
    if ($attribute == 'price' || $attribute == "special_price") {
        $this->addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    } else {
        parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what if two products have same special price and price and position? In my case it doesn't sort by its entity_id then. Do you know how does it sort then?

Answer (score -1):

Only add this in product grid & use index `sprice` to display special price in your grid.

```
$collection->joinAttribute(
    'sprice',
    'catalog_product/special_price',
    'entity_id',
    null,
    'inner'
);
```

Comment: Definitely not, please re read my question I was able to add the special price I just couldn't sort it